# serialization of database objects to send between java webservice and asp.net client web application

Tags: java, asp.net, web-services, serialization

We have a java webservice that provides data for an ASP.NET client web application. The client application asks specific data to the webservice, whichs queries the database and sends the data back.
The data is contained in a class which has a string actionCode, which holds the action to be done, and an object data, which holds the data to be sent to the webservice and back to the client.

To be able to send the data, it has to be serialized, but we can't seem to make it work in both ends. We tried JSON, XML, binary formatting etc, none worked (yet).
The main problem is the fact that we have several types of data (database entities but several others as well) that have to be communicated, using the same generic class (an object as dataholder).

Any suggestions?

Comment: hire a professional software developer.

Comment: since we are a small startup, we do not have the resources for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem the following way:

- using J# (vjslib.dll) to get the same binary formatting from the serialization, because this way we could use the same streams
- we used a data holder that had a string to denote the action to be taken and an object that could hold the data itself. We changed the data holder to be a byte[], which holds the serialized object(s) to be sent. Thus we have serialized data in the serialized object that we sent as a whole.
- java works with signed bytes, c#/ASP.Net does not, so you have to use sbyte at the .Net side.